# Update em banco de dados no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-update

conseguiriam me dizer onde está o erro neste pequeno trecho de código que estou criando para um programa de orçamento com um banco de dados com 4 tabelas (somente o último objeto cmd7 não é aceito na compilação):

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Cliente(nome, endereco)"+"Values (@nome, @endereco)", connect); // nome e endereço do cliente
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Orcamento(id_cliente) SELECT MAX(id) FROM Cliente", connect);//ID do cliente em Orçamento
            OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Orcamento SET data = @data", connect);//data do Orçamento
            OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Item(id_orcam) SELECT MAX(id) FROM Orcamento", connect); //ID do orçamento em Item
            OleDbCommand cmd5 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET quantidade = @quantidade", connect);//quantidade
            OleDbCommand cmd6 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Produto(nome,preco)"+"Values (@nomeProd,@precoProd)", connect); //Nome e preço do produto
            OleDbCommand cmd7 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET id_produto = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Produto)", connect);
            //ESTE ÚLTIMO cmd7 NÃO FUNCIONA

            if(connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@nome",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = nome;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@endereco",OleDbType.Char,20).Value = endereco;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@id_cliente", OleDbType.Char, 20);
                cmd3.Parameters.Add("@data", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = data;
                cmd4.Parameters.Add("@id_orcam", OleDbType.Char, 20);
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@quantidade", OleDbType.Char,20).Value = quantidade;
                cmd6.Parameters.Add("@nome", OleDbType.Char,20).Value = nomeProd;
                cmd6.Parameters.Add("@preco", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = precoProd;
                cmd7.Parameters.Add("@id_produto", OleDbType.Char, 20);

                try
                {
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Já tentei diversas combinações de sintaxe mas parece que que ele não atualiza o o id_produto da tabela Item por causa do último insert feito na tabela Produtos. Alguém consegue enxergar uma solução. 
Obs.: id_produto na tabela Item é uma chave estrangeira sendo herdada da primária da tabela Produto.
Obs2.: o banco foi criado no Access.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você consegue colocar na sua pergunta qual o erro disparado pela execução de `cmd7`?

Comment: Agora estou sem acesso ao código, mas parece que é algo assim: A operação deve usar uma consulta atualizável.

Answer (score 2):

No cmd7, vc não utiliza nenhum parâmetro.

```
 OleDbCommand cmd7 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET id_produto = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Produto)", connect);
```

Mais vc adiciona valor ao parâmetro id_produto:

```
cmd7.Parameters.Add("@id_produto", OleDbType.Char, 20);
```

O problema deve estar neste ponto.

Comment: Achei que cmd7.Parameters.Add fosse necessário informar o tipo de dado onde diz OleDbType.Char. Vou tentar remover esta linha assim que possível. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu tinha imaginado que era isso também, mas as consultas de cima estão da mesma forma e funcionam.

Comment: Mais na realidade no cmd7 o SQL não tem nada como parâmetro utilizando o @ no meio, portanto isso pode estar pirando o command. E @Vanderlei não precisa definir o tipo de dados porque o SQL se encarregará disso, mais é bom verificar, pois, o id_produto tem que ter o mesmo tipo de dados do campo id da tabela produto. verifique ai e se der certo não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta

Comment: Tirei o cmd7.Parameters.Add e executei. Deus o mesmo erro. Mudei o UPDATE por INSERT, acontece o mesmo problema inicial: o id_produto vai para a linha seguinte.

Comment: @Vanderlei, o campo id_produto da tabela item e o campo id da tabela produto são do mesmo tipo de dado?

Comment: Sim. Ambos numéricos. Mas acho que não vem a ser este o problema. Os objetos cmd2 e cmd3 fazem a mesma função que deveria fazer o cmd7 (pegar a primary key e transferi-las para as foreign keys). Se existir um método mais fácil de preencher estes campos com as primary keys já me ajuda.

Comment: Consegui resolver usando "SELECT MAX(id)  FROM Tabela" e capturando o valor através do "cmd.ExecuteScalar()" para variáveis e inserindo-as como parâmetros nos objetos cmd.
Agradeço a contribuição dos amigos.

Comment: @Vanderlei, estamos ai meu caro, pena não termos encontrado a solução aqui na pergunta, mais é um prazer ajudar a comunidade.